# How to clear the memory used by the pool running inside the loop?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have initialized the multiprocessing pool outside the loop and called the process to be executed by the pool inside the loop. The loop continuously runs. A couple of operations are performed by the process. When I see the memory, memory consumption is increased even though the application completes running. Might be the pool running inside the while loop is not releasing the memory. How should I manage the pool so that every time the memory consumption is at the initial state?

```
def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    while True:
        msg_list = /* receives the message from outer source */
        if msg_list:
            for message in msg_list:
                pool.apply_async(process, (message,))

        /* here might be the pool is still consuming the memory. I cannot close the pool since it should continue to run */

def process(bod):
   /* get data from the database */
    res = db.execute("select * from table")
    r_list =[]
    for r in res:
        /* process each row */
        r_list.append(r)

    return r_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is the `process` function doing? We would need to know that.

Comment: Also it's unclear from your code how it can complete running, since it's an infinite loop.